# Setting up Ubuntu for new user

Tags: boot

So I'm donating my desktop to the Salvation Army.  I currently have a fresh install of Ubuntu installed on it with an account I created during install.  Is there a way to set it up so that I can delete my account, turn off the machine, and the next time the machine is turned on it automatically prompts the user to create an account?

Comment: The easiest way is to re-install Ubuntu with "OEM Install" option.

Comment: I would create a Ubuntu DVD. Then delete all the partitions and give it empty to them with the DVD in case they can use it. It is more than likely they are going to put windows on it anyways.

Comment: Remember that you should securely delete all your data before giving it away. Ideally you wipe the entire disk using tools like DBAN.